# starting mysql from the console and my.cnf

Tags: mysql, console

Is this possible to start mysql from the console.

I tried with **mysqld start** but it fails to start, how to start it?

I didn't find **my.cnf** in Mac, I wanted to change **datadir** settings, if there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To start mysql, run `mysqld_safe &`. The ampersand at the end starts the process in the background, so you can continue to work while it runs. Most likely, it needs root privileges to run, so add `sudo` to the front if it doesn't work without (you will need to be logged in as an administrator).

By default, there is no `my.cnf` file. Defaults are used automatically. There are a few different starting files in the `support-files` folder, for different usage styles. You can copy any of them to start with, and place the file in any of these locations (in order searched): /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf $MYSQL_DIR/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf